# Django: How to return a field from a ForeignKey model through filter queryset. As it throws not JSON Serializable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to return a field from the `Contet` model which is a ForeignKey field of `Saved` model. I'm using `filter` queryset since it returns multiple values. But, the problem is I can't return the `slug` field from `Content` model by using `content.slug` after `Saved.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)`!

Content model:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    ...
```

My Saved model:

```
class Saved(models.Model):
    content = models.ForeignKey('Content', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

My view:

```
class SavedList(viewsets.ModelViewset):
    serializer_class = SavedSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Saved.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def list(self, request):
        savedList = []
        for i in self.get_queryset():
            dict = {
                'slug': i.content.slug,  # i want this
                'content': i.content,
                'user': i.user
            }
            savedList.append(dict)
        return Response(savedList)
```

When I'm running this, it's returning `Object of type 'Content' is not JSON Serializable`!

How do I get the `slug` from `Content` model?

Comment: You get the error because of the `'content': i.content,` (not because of `'slug': i.content.slug,`). Moving further why are you not using a serializer?...

Comment: Why is that? It worked fine in python shell! I don't want to include both the `content` and `slug` in the SavedSerializer.

Comment: If you don't want to include both then why are you writing both there?...

Comment: I need the slug as query parameter on the frontend. That's why I'm trying to get slug in this way.

Comment: Do i need to use nested serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the `i` in your `def list()` is the object of class `Content`.

You can achieve it by creating nested serializer as shown below. Probably you won't need the `def list()` method.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
        fields = '__all__' # provide the list fields from `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to include in nested object.

class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = '__all__' # provide the list fields from `Content ` to include in nested object.

class SavedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    content = ContentSerializer(many=True) # this will create a nested object.
    user = UserSerializer(many=True) # this will create a nested object.

    class Meta:
        model = Saved
        fields = ['content', 'user'] # you can add more fields of `Saved` model.
```